# Как скрыть ссылку от посторонних django

Tags: python, django

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Но как сделать, чтобы при переходе на админку django выдавалась ошибка 404. Гуглю битый час, не могу найти, наверное плохо гуглю.

Еще один вопрос: есть ссылки-ответы, по типу "пароль успешно сменился" или "спасибо за регистрацию". Как сделать, чтобы пользователь при наборе ссылки на этот ответ тоже получил какую-то ошибку, но при переходе по jinja ссылке не получал ошибки.

Извиняюсь за плохо изложенную речь. Благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
при переходе на админку django выдавалась ошибка 404
```

пиши миддлварь. в ней ты можешь увидеть путь назначения и получить объект пользователя. и изобразить нужное поведение.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/middleware/

```
ссылки-ответы, по типу "пароль успешно сменился"
```

смотри. эти ответы это ответы на POST запросы, у тебя не должно быть URI для этой станицы. По GET запросу ты видишь форму, по POST запросу тебе выдается результат. для этого достаточно вместо редиректа вернуть html.

второй вариант это использовать сообщения и вообще убрать ссылки-ответы

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: спасибо за ответ. не понял один момент. под ссылкой-ответом я имел в виду:
path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
шаблон по смене пароля. в django прописана ссылка password_change/done/, если по ней просто перейти то будет ответ. я хотел бы его скрыть. Или твой ответ и был ответом на мой вопрос?

Comment: да, Я об этом и говорил. тебе нужно убрать PasswordChangeDoneView. у тебя сейчас в методе, который меняет пароль, есть редирект на PasswordChangeDoneView. убери его и верни либо результат render, либо HttpResponse.

Comment: а для спасибо кнока есть